# Crash by adding data to NSTableView

Tags: swift, xcode, nstableview

I am trying to add data from an array built with classes, to an NSScrollView using an NSArrayController

Here is the class and array:

```swift
class Serie: NSObject {
    @objc dynamic var theID: String
    @objc dynamic var serieName: String
    @objc dynamic var serieAired: String
    @objc dynamic var serieNetwork: String
    @objc dynamic var serieStatus: String

    init(theID: String, serieName: String, serieAired: String, serieNetwork: String, serieStatus: String ) {
        self.theID = theID
        self.serieName = serieName
        self.serieAired = serieAired
        self.serieNetwork = serieNetwork
        self.serieStatus = serieStatus
    }
}

@objc dynamic var Series: [Serie] = []
```

Next I bind the NSArrayController to the array of classes "Series" and linking the TableViewCell to each class item.

[TableView tree image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjz9g.png)
[Bindings & Outlets of ArrayController image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILA3h.png)
[Bindings & Outlets of TableViewCell image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5FaT.png)

The next function is where I populate the "dynamic var Series" that binds the content to the NSArrayController and fills the NSScrollView:

```swift
func GetSerieID(theSerieName: String){

        let url = URL(string: ("https://api.thetvdb.com/search/series?name=" + theSerieName ))!

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.setValue( "Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        //request.setValue( "en", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept-Language")

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No data")
                return
            }

            let json = try? JSON(data: data) // >> I use SwiftyJSON to manage JSON
            let theJSONContent = json!["data"]

            self.Series = [] // >> Empty the array Series

            for (_,subJson):(String, JSON) in theJSONContent {

                let serie = Serie(
                    theID: subJson["id"].stringValue,
                    serieName: subJson["seriesName"].stringValue,
                    serieAired: subJson["firstAired"].stringValue,
                    serieNetwork: subJson["network"].stringValue,
                    serieStatus: subJson["status"].stringValue
                )

                self.Series.append(serie) // >> Here is where it crashes
            }
        }
        task.resume()

        serieTabla.reloadData()
    }
```

From time to time, the TableView does not display or update the view correctly and loads blank data that shows fine a few seconds if you click on it, but normally it works, until more than 10 results are loaded. **Here is the big problem.**

It happens randomly, but usually when you exceed 10-20 items.

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
```

The crash log:

```
miVideoGestor[82269:13639248] *** Assertion failure in -[NSTableRowData _addRowViewForVisibleRow:withPriorView:]
```

I can't figure out the solution.

Could someone give me a clue on how to solve the problem of data loading and display on the tableView?

Thanks in advance guys

Comment: `serieTabla.reloadData()` is at the wrong place. Move it into the closure after the `for` loop and wrap the line in a `DispatchQueue.main` block

Comment: Thanks vadian, it solved the display problem.
Now remains the "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using Cocoa Bindings which is based on Key-Value Observing you have to put any line which affects the UI into a `DispatchQueue.main` block

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.Series = []

    for (_,subJson):(String, JSON) in theJSONContent {

        let serie = Serie(
            theID: subJson["id"].stringValue,
            serieName: subJson["seriesName"].stringValue,
            serieAired: subJson["firstAired"].stringValue,
            serieNetwork: subJson["network"].stringValue,
            serieStatus: subJson["status"].stringValue
        )

        self.Series.append(serie) 
    }
    self.serieTabla.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it! 
Didn't know that the Cocoa Bindings affecting the UI needs to bo in a  DispatchQueue.main block.
Something new learned. ;)